# Need advice on /etc/passwd

Tags: passwd

I am very new to Ubuntu but im picking up the coding relatively quickly --- I have Matlab/arduino experience...

While attempting to set up a VPN, my brother decided to type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> while I was editing the /etc/passwd file and now I cant seem to find it.

With that said, I do not have a password on my ubuntu log in..

If there should be a /passwd in my /etc directory, how can I get in back?

Ive never had a problem like this --- I would appreciate any insight or advice.

Thanks

Comment: Do you still have the shell open from which you had run the editor to edit `/etc/passwd`? If so, the editor is still running, and [fugitive's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/870457/22949) explains how to bring it back. If not, then I recommend you [edit] your question add more information.

Answer (score 3):

Typing `Ctrl + Z` will stop the active process and put it in the background.

```
[1]+  Stopped                 top
```

To view jobs that are in background, go with `jobs` command it will list processes that are in background:

```
jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 top
```

To 'pull' that job in front, use `fg` command, in this case `fg 1`.
Using stortcuts like `Ctrl +Z` , `Ctrl +C` etc means send adequate signal to the current process.

In this case it is `SIGTSTP`. You can read more with **man signal**.

Comment: Or just `fg` by itself will work, if it's the current (most recent) job.